# Is it bad design to structure an entire book as an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller, data-structures, model

I'm building a reading app and need to create a model for books. I'm considering making the entire book's contents an array of strings, with each page being represented by a single string. For a book with hundreds of pages though, this seems like not the best way to structure the data. Is this an appropriate way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: Is this strictly for reading, or will there be some writing?

Comment: It's just a reading app so no writing

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to map every word appearing in the book to a bitset. To do this efficiently, you could define or count the frequency of each word, and encode it using [Huffman codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). This way, common words will have lower sizes.

For instance, the word "the" could be encoded to 001 while the word "magnificent" could be encoded to 011001101110.

Hence, each page would now be a sequence of bitsets.

### Improvement study

---

For simplicity, let's assume we are using a binary tree to encode our words, which is an upper bound to the Huffman codes in terms of average length. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dictionaries_by_number_of_words), the number of words in the English dictionary is 350K. Let us consider the worst case for this new approach in which our text has all 350K words. Then, each word would be encoded to log2(350K) = 19 bits.
Now imagine you have a book of 100 pages with 1500 characters per page. Each char is 1 byte, so you would end up with 100*1500*1 = 150 KB to encode your book.
However, using our binary tree compression, first, we need to divide our text into words: according to [this post](https://wolfgarbe.medium.com/the-average-word-length-in-english-language-is-4-7-35750344870f#:%7E:text=The%20average%20word%20length%20in%20English%20language%20is%204.7%20characters.), the average word length in English is 4.7. Then, if we divide the total number of characters in our book (150K) by 4.7 we get 32K words approximately. Finally, the encoded size of the book would be 19 bits * 32K = 608 Kbits = 76 KB, which reduces by half the original size. This is using a binary tree which is a very rough upper bound of Huffman codes, but it is useful to show that even worst-case-scenarios with upper bounds imply an improvement. So for the actual Huffman codes improvement would need a more complex study, but it would be much larger (I would say a size reduction factor of 10 or 20).

Of course, you would need to consider the map memory size, but for long books, it won't have that much impact I guess.